# When using Contains on a Queue of Arrays the Console returns False. Why?

Tags: c#, arrays, queue, contains

I created a program, in which I have a queue of int arrays:

```
Queue< int[] > Test = new Queue< int[] >();
```

Given an array, I want to check whether the array is inside the Queue.

The namespaces I'm currently using are: System, System.Collections, and System.Collections.Generic.

I tried something like this:

```
Queue<int[]> Test = new Queue<int[]>();

Test.Enqueue(new int[] { 20, 20 });

Console.WriteLine( Test.Contains(new int[] { 20, 20 }) ); // Is the array {20,20} inside the queue?
```

In this code, it seems to me that the Console will output "true", because I added the array {20, 20} to the queue, and now I'm checking using the Contains method.

But when I run the code -- the Console outputs false.

I have two questions:
Why is this happening? And how can I fix this?

Comment: that comparison works on references,you need to create equality comparer or loop through each array and call SequenceEqual and pass   that new array to compare with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because arrays are reference types the comparison will be based on references. Even if the contents are the same your arrays have different references.That's why you get *false*.

To fix that you can implement a custom comparer or you can use `LINQ` methods for example

```
bool arrayExists = Test.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(new[] { 20, 20 }));
```

Comment: On the right track, but will allocate a new array for every test.

Comment: yes, it can be avoided by creating array out of the query.

Answer (score 1):

`Contains()` uses the type's default comparer. For arrays, it compares the array reference, not the contents. You will need to create a custom equality comparer.

Something like this:

```
class ArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
    {
        int h = 0;

        foreach (int item in obj)
        {
            h = (h << 5) + 3 + h ^ item.GetHashCode();
        }

        return h;
    }
}

Test.Contains(new int[] { 20, 20 }, new ArrayComparer())
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are compared by reference by default, not contents. One way of fixing this is to store lists instead of arrays, which will compare contents.  You can convert your arrays into lists before adding to the queue, and back again after taking them out if that's important.